# Android WebView fixed element doesn't respond to click

Tags: android, html, webview, adsense

In my Android Webview I load my webpages. These pages has Adsense in different parts of page. If Adsense exists inside page, click event opens Adsense link in default browser/or asks to open where. That's good.

Problem is:
- If adsense exists fixed in page (like: `style="position: fixed;"`, it can't be clicked. I click to Adsense in portarit and nothing happens. This is problem.
- Adsense is in front of the page. So if there exists a link behind the Adsense image, when I click adsense, them bottom link is opened.
- If I rotate device to landscape Adsense can be clickable, clicking opens new browser.
- I added this `z-index:9999;` to adsense div. But behaviour is the same. Doesn't respond to click.

Also, I have a fixed top navbar (Twitter-bootstrap). When user scrolls down, if there exists a link behind the fixed navbar, if user clicks on navbar, webview opens the link behind the navbar.

So as far as I see, links in the background has much priority then fixed element's links. And some of the fixed elements can't be clicked in portarit ?

This problem occurs in Android 2.3.x. I don't get problem in Android 4.x

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works but try this:

```
webView1.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
```